# How to create hierarchy by using HTML

Tags: html, hierarchy

I want to know is this possible to create hierarchy in web pages by using HTML tags? IF yes, then which HTML tag should I use?

Comment: Could you explain the context for this?

Comment: I want to create a chat application where I want to arrange different chat rooms in hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unordered lists to create a hierarchy (the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags). This can give you a tree structure which is semantically valid, and on top of that you can do whatever you like to express it in interesting ways, either through CSS or Javascript.

Check out [Listutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/) for a great series of worked examples.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context, but lists usually suffice.

Listamatic has [a two level example](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/vertical02.htm), but you can go as deep as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info of exactly what you are trying to represent it is hard to answer, but I will take a stab at it and suggest you use the heading tags `<h1>` through `<h6>`.